Dropdown menu close when open another one
I'm new in Vue.js, I make CRUD project for my coursework.
I'm having trouble with dropdown menu behavior. Can somebody help me?

I want :

dropdown menu without active state automatic closed (collapse), when user try open another dropdown menu without active state.
dropdown menu with active state can't close (collapse) automatic, only user can close or open
when user close (collapse) dropdown menu has active state, I want dropdown menu without active state still open (not collapse) (if already open)

Note:

active state is when user access :active route

isOpen is value dropdown menu open or close (collapse or not collapsed)

sidebarContent.vue, this file contain all menu at sidebar

sidebarCollapsibeItem.vue, this file handle link for dropdown menu

sidebarCollapsible.vue is container for sidebarCollapsibleItem (make dropdown menu)

sidebarLink.vue is like anchor tag at HTML for handle menu without dropdown.


How can I achieve that?
This is my code:
sidebarCollapsible.vue
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { sidebarState } from '@/Composables';
import SidebarLink from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarLink.vue';
import { EmptyCircleIcon } from '@/Components/Icons/Outline';

const props = defineProps({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    icon: {
        required: false,
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
});

const { active } = props;
const isOpen = ref(active);

const beforeEnter = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `0px`;
};
const enter = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `${el.scrollHeight}px`;
};
const beforeLeave = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `${el.scrollHeight}px`;
};
const leave = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `0px`;
};

watch(() => sidebarState.isHovered, (sideHover) => {
    if (!sideHover && !sidebarState.isOpen && !active) {
        isOpen.value = false;
    };
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="relative">
         <SidebarLink @click="isOpen = !isOpen" :title="title" :active="active">
            <template #icon>
                <slot name="icon">
                    <EmptyCircleIcon aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6" />
                </slot>
            </template>

            <template #arrow>
                <span v-show="sidebarState.isOpen || sidebarState.isHovered" aria-hidden="true" class="relative block w-6 h-6 ml-auto">
                    <span :class="['absolute right-[9px] bg-gray-400 mt-[-5px] h-2 w-[2px] top-1/2 transition-all duration-200', {'-rotate-45': isOpen, 'rotate-45': !isOpen}]"></span>
                    <span :class="['absolute left-[9px] bg-gray-400 mt-[-5px] h-2 w-[2px] top-1/2 transition-all duration-200', {'rotate-45': isOpen, '-rotate-45': !isOpen}]"></span>
                </span>
            </template>
        </SidebarLink>

        <transition 
            @before-enter="beforeEnter"
            @enter="enter"
            @before-leave="beforeLeave"
            @leave="leave"
            appear>

            <div v-show="isOpen && (sidebarState.isOpen || sidebarState.isHovered)" class="overflow-hidden transition-all duration-200">
                <ul class="relative px-0 pt-2 pb-0 ml-5 before:w-0 before:block before:absolute before:inset-y-0 before:left-0 before:border-l-2 before:border-l-gray-200 dark:before:border-l-gray-600">
                    <slot />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>


sidebarCollapsibleItem.vue
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const props = defineProps({
    href: String,
    title: String,
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    external: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
});

const { external } = props;

const Tag = external ? 'a' : Link;
</script>

<template>
    <li
        :class="[
            'relative leading-8 m-0 pl-6',
            'before:block before:w-4 before:h-0 before:absolute before:left-0 before:top-4 before:border-t-2 before:border-t-gray-200 before:-mt-0.5',
            'last:before:bg-white last:before:h-auto last:before:top-4 last:before:bottom-0',
            'dark:last:before:bg-dark-eval-1 dark:before:border-t-gray-600',
        ]"
    >
        <component
            :is="Tag"
            :href="href"
            v-bind="$attrs"
            :class="[
                'transition-colors hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-gray-100',
                {
                    'text-purple-500 dark:text-purple-500 hover:text-purple-600 dark:hover:text-purple-600': active,
                    'text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400': !active,
                },
            ]"
        >
            {{ title }}
        </component>
    </li>
</template>

sidebarContent.vue
<script setup>
import PerfrectScrollbar from '@/Components/PerfectScrollbar';
import SidebarLink from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarLink.vue';
import { DashboardIcon } from '@/Components/Icons/Outline';
import { UserGroupIcon, BuildingOffice2Icon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline';
import SidebarCollapsible from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarCollapsible.vue';
import SidebarCollapsibleItem from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarCollapsibleItem.vue';
</script>

<template>
    <PerfrectScrollbar
        tagname="nav"
        aria-label="main"
        class="relative flex flex-col flex-1 max-h-full gap-4 px-3"
    >
        <SidebarLink
            title="Dashboard"
            :href="route('dashboard')"
            :active="route().current('dashboard')"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <DashboardIcon
                    class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>
        </SidebarLink>

        <SidebarCollapsible
            title="Management"
            :active="route().current('users.*') || route().current('teams.*') || route().current('divisions.*') || route().current('departments.*')"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <UserGroupIcon
                class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Users"
                :href="route('users.index')"
                :active="route().current('users.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Roles"
                :href="route('teams.index')"
                :active="route().current('#')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                :href="route('teams.index')"
                title="Teams"
                :active="route().current('teams.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Departments"
                :href="route('departments.index')"
                :active="route().current('departments.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Divisions"
                :href="route('divisions.index')"
                :active="route().current('divisions.*')"
            />
        </SidebarCollapsible>

        <SidebarCollapsible
            title="Locations"
            :active="route().current('externals.*') || route().current('internals.*')"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <BuildingOffice2Icon
                class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Internals"
                :href="route('internals.index')"
                :active="route().current('internals.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Externals"
                :href="route('externals.index')"
                :active="route().current('externals.*')"
            />
        </SidebarCollapsible>

        <SidebarCollapsible
            title="test"
            :active="route().current('api-tokens.*')"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <BuildingOffice2Icon
                class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Internals"
                :href="route('api-tokens.index')"
                :active="route().current('user.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Externals"
                :href="route('api-tokens.index')"
                :active="route().current('api-tokens.*')"
            />

        </SidebarCollapsible>

    </PerfrectScrollbar>
</template>

Thanks for any help, sorry for my bad english.

Review how to ask and also more specifically how to ask about homework.  Explaining what you want your code to do doesn't explain what your code currently does and what actual issues you're facing.  We need much more information: how you expect your code to currently work (walk us through it), expected vs actual results, debugging details (values of variables, whether certain functions are being called, etc.).

your parent component needs to hold the state of which collapsible is open (use and index or id of some kind), clicking to open needs to emit an event back up to the parent, and the parent decides which collapsible shouldbe open. As the code stands I couldn't find anything that tells the sidebar which item should be open/expanded. eg on the click to toggle button: @click="$emit('activeItem', activeItemIdentifier)"

can you give simple example to implement that ??

the docuemntation can https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

thanks for the comment @danielricado
sidebarCollapsible.vue
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { sidebarState } from '@/Composables';
import SidebarLink from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarLink.vue';
import { EmptyCircleIcon } from '@/Components/Icons/Outline';

const props = defineProps({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    icon: {
        required: false,
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    isOpen: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
});

const emit = defineEmits(['toggle']);

const isOpen = ref(props.isOpen || props.active);

watch(() => props.isOpen, (openMenu) => {
    if (!props.active) {
        isOpen.value = openMenu;
    }
});

watch(() => props.active, (activeMenu) => {
    if (activeMenu) {
        isOpen.value = true;
    }
});

watch(() => sidebarState.isHovered, (sideHover) => {
    if (!sideHover && !sidebarState.isOpen) {
        if (!props.active) {
            emit('toggle', null);
        } else {
            isOpen.value = true;
        }
    }
});


const beforeEnter = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `0px`;
};
const enter = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `${el.scrollHeight}px`;
};
const beforeLeave = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `${el.scrollHeight}px`;
};
const leave = (el) => {
    el.style.maxHeight = `0px`;
};

const toggle = () => {
    isOpen.value = !isOpen.value;

    if (!props.active) {
        emit('toggle', props.id);
    }
};
</script>

<template>
    <div class="relative">
        <SidebarLink @click="toggle" :title="title" :active="props.active">
            <template #icon>
                <slot name="icon">
                    <EmptyCircleIcon aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6" />
                </slot>
            </template>

            <template #arrow>
                <span v-show="sidebarState.isOpen || sidebarState.isHovered" aria-hidden="true" class="relative block w-6 h-6 ml-auto">
                    <span :class="['absolute right-[9px] bg-gray-400 mt-[-5px] h-2 w-[2px] top-1/2 transition-all duration-200', {'-rotate-45': isOpen, 'rotate-45': !isOpen}]"></span>
                    <span :class="['absolute left-[9px] bg-gray-400 mt-[-5px] h-2 w-[2px] top-1/2 transition-all duration-200', {'rotate-45': isOpen, '-rotate-45': !isOpen}]"></span>
                </span>
            </template>
        </SidebarLink>

        <transition 
            @before-enter="beforeEnter"
            @enter="enter"
            @before-leave="beforeLeave"
            @leave="leave"
            appear>

            <div v-show="isOpen && (sidebarState.isOpen || sidebarState.isHovered)" class="overflow-hidden transition-all duration-200">
                <ul class="relative px-0 pt-2 pb-0 ml-5 before:w-0 before:block before:absolute before:inset-y-0 before:left-0 before:border-l-2 before:border-l-gray-200 dark:before:border-l-gray-600">
                    <slot />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

sidebarContent.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import PerfectScrollbar from '@/Components/PerfectScrollbar';
import SidebarLink from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarLink.vue';
import { DashboardIcon } from '@/Components/Icons/Outline';
import { UserGroupIcon, BuildingOffice2Icon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline';
import SidebarCollapsible from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarCollapsible.vue';
import SidebarCollapsibleItem from '@/Components/Sidebar/SidebarCollapsibleItem.vue';

const openCollapsibleId = ref(null);

const toggleCollapsible = (id) => {
    openCollapsibleId.value = openCollapsibleId.value === id ? null : id;
};
</script>

<template>
    <PerfectScrollbar
        tagname="nav"
        aria-label="main"
        class="relative flex flex-col flex-1 max-h-full gap-4 px-3"
    >
        <SidebarLink
            title="Dashboard"
            :href="route('dashboard')"
            :active="route().current('dashboard')"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <DashboardIcon
                    class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>
        </SidebarLink>

        <SidebarCollapsible
            id="management"
            title="Management"
            :active="route().current('users.*') || route().current('teams.*') || route().current('divisions.*') || route().current('departments.*')"
            :is-open="openCollapsibleId === 'management'"
            @toggle="toggleCollapsible"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <UserGroupIcon
                class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Users"
                :href="route('users.index')"
                :active="route().current('users.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Roles"
                :href="route('teams.index')"
                :active="route().current('#')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                :href="route('teams.index')"
                title="Teams"
                :active="route().current('teams.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Departments"
                :href="route('departments.index')"
                :active="route().current('departments.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Divisions"
                :href="route('divisions.index')"
                :active="route().current('divisions.*')"
            />
        </SidebarCollapsible>

        <SidebarCollapsible
            id="locations"
            title="Locations"
            :active="route().current('externals.*') || route().current('internals.*')"
            :is-open="openCollapsibleId === 'locations'"
            @toggle="toggleCollapsible"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <BuildingOffice2Icon
                class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Internals"
                :href="route('internals.index')"
                :active="route().current('internals.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Externals"
                :href="route('externals.index')"
                :active="route().current('externals.*')"
            />
        </SidebarCollapsible>

        <SidebarCollapsible
            id="test"
            title="test"
            :active="route().current('api-tokens.*')"
            :is-open="openCollapsibleId === 'test'"
            @toggle="toggleCollapsible"
        >
            <template #icon>
                <BuildingOffice2Icon
                class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                />
            </template>

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Internals"
                :href="route('api-tokens.index')"
                :active="route().current('user.*')"
            />

            <SidebarCollapsibleItem
                title="Externals"
                :href="route('api-tokens.index')"
                :active="route().current('api-tokens.*')"
            />

        </SidebarCollapsible>
    </PerfectScrollbar>
</template>

